# Google Colab Notebook completely freezes when training a YOLO model

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, object-detection, yolo

I am following a tutorial to train custom object detection model using YOLO.
[This is the tutorial and also where I got the Notebook](https://pysource.com/2020/04/02/train-yolo-to-detect-a-custom-object-online-with-free-gpu)

Everything works fine until the training bit which is the last cell. It complete a few iterations then it freezes and the page stops responding. I’m in a little hurry so any way to fix this is appreciated. TIA

Comment: In collab, are you setting the runtime to GPU or TPU?

Comment: @jakub using GPU

Comment: Could you send an image of where exactly it freezes?

Answer (score 2):

```
from IPython.utils import io
with io.capture_output() as captured:
   !./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/yolov3_training.cfg darknet53.conv.74 - 
   dont_show
```

I had same issue, this one worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Darknet was giving so much output that the webpage was hitting memory limits. I solved the problem by clearing the output every few minutes.

Comment: Can you please show an example of how to do that?. Your answer and your question are poorly detailed. Thanks anyway.