# YOLO darknet freezes when I start training my model

Tags: google-colaboratory, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I am training a model with yolo darknet in google colab but when I start the training the page freezes and a pop-up window appears that the web page does not respond
I don't know if it is because the model has many classes to train and the page collapses

here is my code:

```
!apt-get update
!unzip "/content/drive/My Drive/custom_dib_model/darknet.zip"
!sudo apt install dos2unix
!find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix
!chmod +x /content/darknet
!make
!./darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights data/person.jpg
!rm /content/darknet/backup -r
!ln -s /content/drive/'My Drive'/dib_weights/backup /content/darknet
!./darknet detector train dibujos_dataset/dib.data dib_yolov4.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -map -dont_show
```

The last line is the one that begins the training of my model and about 5 min pass when the page freezes, it should be noted that no error appears

I found a similar question but there is no concrete answer
[possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64599214/google-colab-notebook-completely-freezes-when-training-a-yolo-model) by the user

This is all the information that I can give you and I hope it is enough

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the YOLO configuration `dib_yolo.cfg` file modifying the subdivisions from 64 to 16